# Composer: Command Not Found

Tags: php, composer-php

From within the directory holding my composer.phar file, I can't execute any composer commands.

I can see Composer is running when I execute

```
php composer.phar
```

But any direct composer statements fail.

Not sure if it matters but Composer was included within a cloned repository.

I just want to install a single Oauth library, then likely not touch Composer again for several months, so I don't need to run it globally. I'm just confused why I can't run Composer from within this directory.

Comment: Windows, Mac, or Linux machine?

Comment: What is a 'direct composer statement'?

Comment: `php composer.phar require foo/bar`

Comment: We need more information to be any help here. Do you have an error message? What command are you trying to run that's failing?

Comment: an example statement would be "composer -v". I get a Command Not Found error. I'm on a Mac

Comment: What's the exact problem? `composer -v` is not the same as `php composer.phar -v`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Your `composer.phar` command lacks the flag for executable, or it is not inside the path.

The first problem can be fixed with `chmod +x composer.phar`, the second by calling it as `./composer.phar -v`.

You have to prefix executables that are not in the path with an explicit reference to the current path in Unix, in order to avoid going into a directory that has an executable file with an innocent name that looks like a regular command, but is not. Just think of a `cat` in the current directory that does not list files, but deletes them.

The alternative, and better, fix for the second problem would be to put the `composer.phar` file into a location that is mentioned in the path

Comment: Prefixing a reference to the current directory worked, ./composer.phar -v. Thanks for the answer, thank you also for the explaination!

Answer (score 214):

This problem arises when you have composer installed locally.
To make it globally executable,run the below command in terminal

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for composer 1.3.1 on OSX 10.10, thankyou

Comment: "-- sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer" or "sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer" it helps if you actually use a code block

Comment: For me, the command has worked after opening a new console (to take effect)

Comment: Thanks, worked.

Do you know, that in 12 years since I am doing stuff on unix/debian it NEVER happened that one of the commands I found worked in the first place? there is ALWAYS an error, and I always have to GOOGLE and fix it..bla.bla..

Comment: i am getting the error mv: rename composer.phar to /usr/local/bin/composer: No such file or directory

Comment: Note that when moved, the ".phar" extension is removed from the file name.

Answer (score 89):

I am using CentOS and had same problem.

I changed `/usr/local/bin/composer` to `/usr/bin/composer` and it worked.

Run below command :

`curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php 
 sudo mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer`

Verify Composer is installed or not

`composer --version`

Comment: This was what fixed my issue on Amazon AWS CentOS

Comment: This fixed my problem sudo mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer

Comment: This worked for me, thanks @bsb

Comment: Your system path is set up incorrectly if it doesn't include `/usr/local/bin/`

Answer (score 45):

This is for **mac or ubuntu** user, try this on terminal

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

or **mac brew** can try

```
brew install composer
```

Answer (score 38):

**MacOS:** composer is available on brew now (Tested on Php7+):

```
brew install composer
```

[Install instructions on the Composer Docs page](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-macos) are quite to the point otherwise.

Answer (score 13):

Step 1 : Open Your terminal

Step 2 :  Execute the following command

```
          curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Step 3 :  After installation run below command

```
          sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/
```

Step 4 :  Open bash_profile file create alias follow below steps

```
           vim ~/.bash_profile
```

Step 5 : Add below line in `.bash_profile` file

```
          alias composer="php /usr/local/bin/composer.phar"
```

Step 6 : Close your terminal and reopen your terminal and run below command

```
          composer
```

Comment: on run this command 

sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/

get bolow issue

sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is world writable
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set

Comment: yes its work for me alias composer="php /usr/local/bin/composer"

Answer (score 12):

First I did alias setup on bash / zsh profile.

```
alias composer="php /usr/local/bin/composer.phar"
```

Then I  moved composer.phar to `/usr/local/bin/`

```
cd /usr/local/bin
mv composer.phar composer
```

Then made composer executable by running

```
sudo chmod +x composer
```

Answer (score -1):

https://getcomposer.org/download/
it might help

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '906a84df04cea2aa72f40b5f787e49f22d4c2f19492ac310e8cba5b96ac8b64115ac402c8cd292b8a03482574915d1a8') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
```

this code for ubuntu and wsl2.

Answer (score -1):

Open terminal and run the following command,

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/php71 /usr/bin/php
```

Answer (score -1):

Works in RHEL 8, php 7.4

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer
```